# Unable to access div content from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I only see the space tags `"\r\n                  "\r\n"` for InnerHTML & InnerText properties and not the actual content. Where am i going wrong

**RENDERED HTML:**

```
<div id="urllist" runat="server">
http://test1t.com
<br></br>
http://test2.com
<br></br>
</div>
```

**C#:**

```
HtmlContainerControl list = (HtmlContainerControl)urllist;
string string1 = list.InnerHtml;
string string2 = list.InnerText;

//this didnt work either
string string1 = urllist.InnerHtml;
string string2 = urllist.InnerText;
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see only `"\r\n                  "\r\n"`? Because I tested your code above and it works!

Comment: for string1 & string2

Comment: @Qwerty: i think that SmartDev means where you _see_ it, in the debugger?

Comment: oh yes when debugging.(In both cases). Even when I used htmlgeneric instead of htmlcontainer

Comment: I think I found the issue. The content in div is dynamically generated in my case. Is this the reason it shows in html but not at server end

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly you have to use `Controls[0]` to find the literal control that contains the text:

```
var div = (HtmlGenericControl) urllist;
var lit = (LiteralControl) div.Controls[0];
string text = lit.Text;
```

**Update**: tested, it works. This is `text`:

```
http://test1t.com
<br></br>
http://test2.com
<br></br>
```

However, now i have tested it with your approach and it works also.

Comment: I get the text only as `"\r\n                     "\r\n"`

Comment: @Qwerty: i have tested it with your aspx and my codebehind.

Comment: Where is it going wrong for me. Is it because the page has a master. Did you use an asp:literal control inside the div?

Comment: @Qwerty: i have now also tested your code and it works also. **Edit** no, i have used your code. The literal-control is added implictly by ASP.NET. You cannot see it. I don't know why it could be relevant that you use a master-page.

Answer (score 1):

I would have added a comment, but I cannot add images in comments. See below, I've tested your code and it works:

[image]

[image]

Are you sure you don't check your result in a HTML page or that you are not altering your result in any way before you check it?

Comment: I check in the html. and no alteration for sure. the code is just as in the image. The div in html renders as `<div id="ctl00_cpContent_urllist" class="urllist">' but its id is urllist, so that shouldnt be relevant i guess